# getting error Invalid property 'packagesToScan' of bean class[..]. Bean property 'packagesToScan' is not writable or has an invalid setter method

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am getting the following error

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid 
>       property 'packagesToScan' of bean 
>       class[org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Bean
>       property 'packagesToScan' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does 
>       the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?\

I am using spring3.2. Dependencies are added using MAven. Everything seems ok. Why i am getting this error. Here is my file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.3.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

....
<bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>        
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="pk.training.basitMahmood.domain"/>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">50</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>              
        </props>        
    </property>
</bean>    

<context:annotation-config/> 

.....

</beans>
```

Thanks

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

dont know about your packagesToScan?
hope you using annotation like `@Table, @Entity, @column ...`
you dont need any packages to be scanned.
when you will try to crud an entity, hibernate will read the annotation
my answer is just to remove that line

**UPDATE**
*config.dao.xml*

```
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:./META-INF/persistence.xml" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">50</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

*persitence.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="default" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Comment: No, if i remove the line, then i get the error that `Error creating bean with name 'emf' defined in class path resource [datasource-tx-jpa.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No persistence units parsed from {classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml}`

Comment: create a persitence.xml, in META-INF, I will give you a sample

Comment: Thanks. I tried but now i am getting the following exception `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'emf' defined in class path resource [datasource-tx-jpa.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo.getSharedCacheMode()Ljavax/persistence/SharedCacheMode;`

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue. Actually i think my POM was not correct. I was making the spring MVC project and firstly my POM is like below. I think using this POM i had so many jar conflicts, as maven use transitive approach to download jars.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>pk.training.basitMahmood</groupId>
<artifactId>ch17_ThemingAndTemplating</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>ch17_ThemingAndTemplating Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <org.springframework-version>3.2.2.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.Beta2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.Beta2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Draft-16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.171</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time-hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time-jsptags</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>14.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>ch17_ThemingAndTemplating</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target> 
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

But when i changed my POM to

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>pk.training.basitMahmood</groupId>
    <artifactId>ch17_WebApplicationWithSpring</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>ch17_WebApplicationWithSpring Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>3.2.3.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.7.5</org.slf4j-version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate entity manager with JPA 2 support. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.Beta2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate’s implementation of JSR-303. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- The JSR-303 Bean Validation API library. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- H2 database for embedded JDBC database. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.171</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Joda-time (joda-time.sourceforge.net/) is a date-time API that Spring Data JPA uses. We will 
    use it in our domain objects too. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Joda-time library for integration with Hibernate for date-time data persistence. For hibernate 3
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time-hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>   <!-- Hibernate 4  -->
        <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.CR6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Contains useful helper classes. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>14.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>   

    <!-- Logging 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- @Inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
<finalName>WebApplicationWithSpring</finalName>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
            <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.6</target>
            <!-- specifiy which directory within the project hierarchy will be considered as the root directory from the 
                 generated war file 
            <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
            -->
        </configuration>

    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Then things start got working. The error gone. Hope this will help others too. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looking into Spring 3.2.3 source, i noticed that in fact there's no `getPackagesToScan()` in `org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` method, so, `BeanUtils` is right to launch this exception!